# Epimorphisms in two directions

Tags: category-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category. Consider the following statement:

(S1) Whenever $A,B$ are objects and $\iota_1:A\to B$ and $\iota_2:B\to A$ are monomorphisms, then there is an isomorphism $\phi:A\to B$.

(For instance, (S1) holds in the category of groups, but not in the category of topological spaces with continuous maps.)

Let (S2) be the statement that we get from (S1) by replacing "mono" by "epi". Are (S1) and (S2) equivalent?

Comment: The category $\mathbf{Grp}$ of groups does not satisfy the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein property. Consider for example the free group on two generators. Its commutator subgroup is free on countably many generators, so each of $F_2$ and $F_\mathbb{N}$ embed into the other one but yet they are not isomorphic.

Comment: I am pretty sure that (S1) and (S2) are not equivalent. (S1) is studied in the paper "The Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein property in categories" by Don Laackman (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Laackman.pdf). For certain categories of modules (S1) and (S2) are studied in the paper "Correct classes of modules" by Robert Wisbauer (http://www.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~wisbauer/adm_correct.pdf).

Comment: Probably the simplest example which demonstrates that $\mathsf{Grp}$ and $\mathsf{Ab}$ don't satisfy (S1) consists of the two groups $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/4 \times \mathbb{Z}/4 \times \dotsc$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4 \times \mathbb{Z}/4 \times \mathbb{Z}/4 \times \dotsc $.